# Postfix does not trigger my before-queue milter script

Tags: postfix, milter

I can't get the milter triggered when a new email is accepted by Postfix before-queue. Obviously, I don't do something properly but I can't figure out what.

I have the following setup: Ubuntu Server, Postfix 2.11.

The Postfix service is working and receives emails to the local accounts properly.

Script /tmp/milter.sh (owner: me, group: me, permission: rwx-rwx-rx) logs some string each time it's run. It works properly when launched under user me in the terminal.

In `/etc/postfix/master.cf`, I have:

```
smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
   -o content_filter=mymilter

...

mymilter    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=F user=me argv=/tmp/milter.sh
```

The new configuration is loaded by

```
sudo postfix reload
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you confused about Milter, before and after queue filter. Those three items was different from each other. I suggest you to read the documentation about [Postfix Milter support](http://www.postfix.org/MILTER_README.html), [before queue filter](http://www.postfix.org/SMTPD_PROXY_README.html) and [after queue filter](http://www.postfix.org/FILTER_README.html).

Parameter `content_filter` indicated that you run AFTER-QUEUE content filter. Snippet about this parameter from [Postfix documentation](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#content_filter)

> **After the message is queued**, send the entire message to the specified *transport:destination*. The *transport* name specifies the first field of a mail delivery agent definition in master.cf; the syntax of the *next-hop destination* is described in the manual page of the corresponding delivery agent. More information about external content filters is in the Postfix [FILTER_README](http://www.postfix.org/FILTER_README.html) file.

And your question about why it isn't working, please check the maillog. My guess that you should add `mymilter:dummy` instead only `mymilter` in parameter content_filter. See the example in t[his official documentation](http://www.postfix.org/FILTER_README.html#simple_filter).

The final note, if you modify `master.cf` then it would preferable to use `postfix stop; postfix start` to make postfix read the configuration.